# Can't change root password: "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

I'm trying to change the root password in MySQL on my development machine (I've just installed MySQL, so it currently doesn't have a password), but it keeps failing with the following error message:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm using MySQL 5.1.70 (x86, 32-bit) on Windows 7 SP1 (64 bits). I've added MySQL's "bin" directory to my "Path" environment variable.

In the [comments of the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html#comments), I read that I should have installed the service using the absolute path, so I stopped MySQL, and uninstalled it:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mysqld --remove
Service successfully removed.
```

Then I installed it again, using the absolute path this time:

```
C:\Windows\system32>C:\web\mysql-5.1.70\bin\mysqld.exe --install
Service successfully installed.
```

I started MySQL, and tried to change the password again:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mysqladmin -u root password Pe%8XiduwOqdZ<ZFE5!
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also tried with quotes:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mysqladmin -u root password 'Pe%8XiduwOqdZ<ZFE5!'
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I also tried to change the current directory to MySQL's "bin" directory:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\web\mysql-5.1.70\bin

C:\web\mysql-5.1.70\bin>mysqladmin -u root password Pe%8XiduwOqdZ<ZFE5!
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\web\mysql-5.1.70\bin>mysqladmin -u root password 'Pe%8XiduwOqdZ<ZFE5!'
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: How about " instead of ' around your password? Windows doesn't recognize the single quote character like unix.

Answer (score 1):

There are two techniques you can try:

### TECHNIQUE #1

The comment from [Michael - sqlbot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11651/michael-sqlbot) already said it. Use double quotes

```
mysqladmin -u root password "Pe%8XiduwOqdZ<ZFE5!"
```

### TECHNIQUE #2

`root@localhost` has no password. Try running this:

```
mysql -uroot -e"SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0; SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('mynewpassword');"
```

This should do it as well.

**CAVEAT FOR MySQL 5.6 users** : TECHNIQUE #2 will not work in Linux for MySQL 5.6. There is a separate file with the temp password for root@localhost ( `${HOME}/.mysql_secret` ). You login with that password and change the password from there.

### Give it a Try !!!